# C# - WPF Custom User Control multiple times same view

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

We develop a kind of date capture component under our client specification, this component have to be used in all the view where we capture dates but if we put this component multiple times in the same view values changes in all the compnent when we update any of them.

This the code for my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.Views.CalendarView"
         cal:Bind.Model="Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels.CalendarViewModel" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.Views"
         xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.Views.Controls"
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         d:DesignHeight="110" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Margin="3,3,3,3">
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <local1:AutoFocusText x:Name="Day" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Day , ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  MaxLength="2"  BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Margin =" 0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Margin =" 0,0,0,0" Text="/"/>
                </Label>
                <local1:AutoFocusText x:Name="Month" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Month,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  MaxLength="2" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Margin =" 0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderBrush}">
                    <TextBlock  Margin =" 0,0,0,0" Text="/"/>
                </Label>
                <local1:AutoFocusText x:Name="Year" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Year,  ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  MaxLength="4" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

This is the code of the ViewModel:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels.Interface;
using System;
namespace Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels
{
public class CalendarViewModel : Screen, ICalendarViewModel
{
    private DateTime? date;
    public bool validate;
    public CalendarViewModel()
    {
        date = new DateTime();

        validate = false;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Day);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Month);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Year);
    }

    private const string DAY_MASK = "DD";
    private const string MONTH_MASK = "MM";
    private const string YEAR_MASK = "YYYY";


    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            return date;
        }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Day);
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Month);
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Year);
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Date);
        }
    }

    private void CrearFecha()
    {
        if (ValidateInformation())
        {
            date = new DateTime(year ?? default(int), month ?? default(int), day ?? default(int));
            day = date.Value.Day;
            month = date.Value.Month;
            year = date.Value.Year;
        }
        else
        {
            date = null;
            day = null;
            month = null;
            year = null;
        }
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Day);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Month);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Year);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Date);


    }

    public bool ValidateInformation()
    {
        int maxDay;
        bool validate = false;
        if (IsMasked())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (year < DateTime.MinValue.Year || year > DateTime.MaxValue.Year)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (month == null || year == null)
        {
            maxDay = 30;
        }
        else
        {
            maxDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year ?? default(int), month ?? default(int));
        }

        if (day < 1 || day >= maxDay)
        {
            return false;
        }

        validate = true;
        return validate;
    }

    private Nullable<int> day;
    public string Day
    {
        get
        {
            return day != null ? day.ToString() : DAY_MASK;
        }
        set
        {
            int d;
            int.TryParse(value, out d);
            if (d > 0)
            {
                day = d;
            }
            else
            {
                day = null;
            }
            UpdateDate();
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Day);
        }
    }
    private Nullable<int> month;

    public string Month
    {
        get
        {
            return month != null ? month.ToString() : MONTH_MASK;
        }
        set
        {
            int m;
            int.TryParse(value, out m);
            if (m > 0)
            {
                month = m;
            }
            else
            {
                month = null;
            }
            UpdateDate();
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Month);
        }
    }
    private Nullable<int> year;

    public string Year
    {
        get
        {
            return year != null ? year.ToString() : YEAR_MASK;
        }
        set
        {
            int y;
            int.TryParse(value, out y);
            if (y > 0)
            {
                year = y;
            }
            else
            {
                year = null;
            }
            UpdateDate();
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Year);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateDate()
    {
        if (!IsMasked())
        {
            CrearFecha();
        }
        else
        {
            Date = null;
        }
    }


    public bool Validate
    {
        get { return validate; }
        set { validate = value; }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return this["Day"] + this["Month"] + this["Year"];
        }

    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "Day":
                case "Month":
                case "Year":
                    if (ValidateInformation())
                    {
                        validate = false;
                        return string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        validate = true;
                        return "Fecha Invalida";
                    }

            }
            validate = false;
            return string.Empty;

        }
    }

    private bool IsMasked()
    {
        return DAY_MASK.Equals(Day) || MONTH_MASK.Equals(Month) || YEAR_MASK.Equals(Year);
    }

}
}
```

This is the interface code:

```
using System;

namespace Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels.Interface

{
public interface ICalendarViewModel
{
    bool Validate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    DateTime? Date
    {
        get;
    }
}
}
```

And here thew code of the view where we are using this component:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.Views.LogQueryView"
         cal:Bind.Model="Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels.LogQueryViewModel" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.Views"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Start Date"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="End Date"></Label>
    <local:CalendarView x:Uid="DateStart" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="DateStartView"/>
    <local:CalendarView x:Uid="DateEnd" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DateEndView"/>
</Grid>
```

And this is the View Model:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels.Interface;

namespace Mx.Gob.Biometrics.UniversalBiometric.ViewModels

{
public class LogQueryViewModel : Screen, ILogQueryViewModel
{
    private ICalendarViewModel dateStartView;
    private ICalendarViewModel dateEndView;

    public LogQueryViewModel()
    {
        dateStartView = new CalendarViewModel();
        dateEndView = new CalendarViewModel();
    }

    public ICalendarViewModel DateStartView
    {
        get
        {
            return dateStartView;
        }
        set
        {
            dateStartView = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DateStartView);
        }

    }
    public ICalendarViewModel DateEndView
    {
        get
        {
            return dateEndView;
        }
        set
        {
            dateEndView = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DateEndView);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: How are you managing the lifetime of your viewmodels?  Is the same instance being used to back each separate control?

Comment: I creating a intance for each control, I am not putting them in the container due to I need to isolate the behaivor per field. In the contrusctor of the LogQueryViewModel I'm creating the instance for each one: dateStartView = new CalendarViewModel();
        dateEndView = new CalendarViewModel();

Comment: I think the problem is in the Notifies and how caliburn micro take care of them. But I don't know how to isolate the notify to an specif control. My control internally have 3 properties: Day, Month and Year and I'm notifying them when the field change the value: this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Day);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Month);
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Year);

Comment: I see (misleadingly named) DateStartView and DateEndView properties in your LogQueryViewModel, but how they get to be the DataContexts of the respective usercontrols? There's no assignment and no binding anywhere. Did you assume that naming a control after a property will somehow cause WPF to generate a binding?

Comment: In fact, Caliburn did it for you. Caliburn use the x:Name to made the binding.

Comment: @MiguelResendiz Interesting. What's the exact problem you're having? My cautious best guess is that you're saying that `DateStartView` and `DateEndView` are both showing the same date, but it's not altogether clear if "component" refers to the usercontrol or to CalendarView. It's also not clear what "values changes in all the compnent" mean. Are you saying they change arbitrarily, or they change so they're all the same, or what?

Comment: I mean, when I change the value of date in DateStartView and move to other field it also change in the DateEndView and vice versa. But if I put the control in different views it work correctly.